# Hidden UITabBar still crops any UIView that's put on top of it

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

I've been trying to add a UIView (with a UIImageView) as an initial screen when the user launches my application for the first time. However, even after I hide the tab bar, or move its frame out of the screen, the UIView still crops itself as if the tab bar was still there.

Both of these code blocks produced the same result:

```
[appDelegate.tabBarController.tabBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0,1000,0,0)];
[self setView:InitialView];
```

and

```
[appDelegate.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
[self setView:InitialView];
```

Here's a screenshot of the incident in action:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I've been puzzling away at this for the past few hours, and I can't seem to do anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this reference your App Delegate which should take in account the UITabBarController.  Just the UIImageView as a subview, and when you are done just remove it.  You'll obviously have to import your AppDelegate.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

[imageView addSubview:appDelegate.window];
```

Comment: I'm a little unsure of what you're trying to say, but I attempted to implement your instructions. Using the line of code `[appDelegate.window addSubview:initialView]` the [output](http://i.imgur.com/jxyeQ.png) was a bit strange. I'm not exactly sure what's going on there, and every time I tried moving around the UIViews, nothing seemed to change (`insertSubview: atIndex: and aboveSubview:` didn't do anything). However, I'm excited that there is a different result than before, and I'll keep fiddling around! :)

Comment: Aha! I finally was able to figure out the solution: `[appDelegate.tabBarController.tabBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0,1000,0,0)];        
        [appDelegate.window addSubview:initialView];
        [mainView setHidden:YES];
        
        [appDelegate.window addGestureRecognizer:SwipeDetector];` did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have your view's view controller inside this tab bar controller. As a result, the view controller's view is getting sized appropriately to fit inside the tab bar controller's view. Why don't you just get the frame of the tab bar and adjust the height of your view by the view's current height + the tab bar's height?

As a side note, I am assuming `InitialView` is a UIView (or subclass) instance. It is standard Object-Oriented Programming convention to name instances of classes with a lower case letter, and then to proceed in camel case, as in `initialView`. Just an FYI.

Comment: Ah, sorry about the violation of the title-case convention, I should have adjusted that ages ago. Regarding your solution, unfortunately I already tried that, to no avail. When I make the frame of initialView that of the entire window (the view's height + 49, seeing at the tab bar is 49 pixels high) there is hardly any visible change. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/2uf19.png)'s a screenshot after I adjusted the y-values and the height-values of initialView's frame.

Comment: You shouldn't have to change y. The origin should still be at 0,0.

Comment: Unfortunately, using the lines of code: `[self setView:initialView];`
        `[initialView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [self view].frame.size.width, [self view].frame.size.height + 49)];
       ` still gives me [this](http://i.imgur.com/edpKK.png) result. :/